# How can I combine these two model fields into one?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Let's say I have this model:

```
class ParticipationCount(models.Model):

    female = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    male   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I would like to combine them permanently into:

```
people = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I would like for all the existing male and female ones to both be combined into "people." As we already use this model and have data.

Here is the admin:

```
class ParticipationCountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("shift_datetime", "shift", "location", "female", "male")
    search_fields = ["location", "female", "male"]
    form = ParticipationCountForm
```

So, in summary, how do I combine the "male" and "female" into one field, and **continue using this field from here on out**, because we don't refer to genders anymore.

Comment: Add the field in one migration, then create a second migration to populate it with female+male, then a third to delete the old fields.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure I can gather what you're saying 100%, can you make an answer and explain a little more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Daniel Roseman's comment, you can do it in the following way:

**STEP 1**: Add the field `people` to your model, like so:

```
class ParticipationCount(models.Model):
    female = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    male   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    people = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Then run the commands `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

**STEP 2**: Next, create your own migration file:

```
def set_people(apps, schema_editor):
    ParticipationCount = apps.get_model('your_app', 'ParticipationCount')
    for row in ParticipationCount.objects.all():
        row.people = row.male + row.female
        row.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_app', '...'),  # fill in your previous migration number
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_people),
    ]
```

Then run the command `python manage.py migrate`

**STEP 3**: Remove the `male` and `female` fields, like so:

```
class ParticipationCount(models.Model):
    people = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Then run the commands `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

---

For more info on writing your own migrations, take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/writing-migrations/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I just have one question, what should I set the default for people to so it won't cause problems? It's telling me this: ```You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'people' to participationcount without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).``` and I'm not sure if making it null is good or not

Comment: Use zero as default. After the first migration the field is not in use. After the second, it is filled with the sum of the other two fields. Before the third, you have to change all references to male or female in your code to be referernces to people,, because after running the third the fields will be gone and the code would crash.